# Flex/Air - mobile multi-touch development with multi-touch LCD monitor

Tags: apache-flex, air, multi-touch, lcd

This may appear at first a bit of a general question, but its actually quite specific.

Is it feasible to use (or worth buying) a multi-touch monitor for developing and testing mobile Flex/Air applications? For instance one could use the Android emulator and package their Air 2.5 app to run in the emulator, and then use the multi-touch LCD to test it out. Rather than continually downloading the app to the mobile device.

Has anyone tried this?

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that would work.  The problem here is the hardware isn't connected to the software the same way as on a device (which goes through firmware).  In this case, it's going through the OS (which I'm not even sure support multitouch) and then the emulator(which I'm not positive will even take in multitouch input from the OS).  The emulator might not even have multitouch code in it.

I would stick with using the device.  I don't see why that's a problem.  If you streamline the compile/deploy/debug process, it's even easier than using the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, your right, LCD->OS->Emulator wouldnt work. Another showstopper is that the emulator doesnt support multi touch at all

Comment: That's what I figured.  Try to streamline your build/deploy/debug process to the device and it will be much better that way.